# Find the dependency that brought another dependency in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Now that [npm installs dependencies in a flat structure](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5) the `node_modules` dir is crowded with lots and lots of dependencies and I have a hard time tracing why a particular dependency is there.

For example, when installing one of my dependencies, I get a warning that [cross-spawn-asyc](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn-async) is deprecated and [cross-spawn](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) should be used instead. But having a closer look I see that my dependency is actually using *cross-spawn* but apparently something deeper in its dependency hierarchy still uses the old *cross-spawn-async* library.

How can I find that dependency which causes this problem rather than going through `package.json` of 100+ directories under `node_modules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this npm command may help:

```
npm ls <package_name>
```

It will show you the structure of dependencies to your package as tree. The package you are looking for will be shown in different color or highlighted in another way, so it will be easy to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls):

```
npm ls cross-spawn-asya
```

This will show all the dependency trees that include the given package. This could look similar to (with the example of minimatch):

```
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.6.0
| `-- babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.6.5
|   `-- babel-core@6.7.6
|     `-- minimatch@2.0.10 
+-- forever@0.15.1
| `-- forever-monitor@1.6.0
|   `-- minimatch@2.0.10 
+-- glob@7.0.3
| `-- minimatch@3.0.0 
+-- grunt-contrib-jshint@0.11.3
| `-- jshint@2.8.0
|   +-- cli@0.6.6
|   | `-- glob@3.2.11
|   |   `-- minimatch@0.3.0 
|   `-- minimatch@2.0.10
```